# any danger in splicing tinned copper and normal copper?

Tags: electrical, wiring

It is difficult and dangerous to combine aluminum and copper wiring.  Are there any pitfalls with respect to tinned copper and copper?

Comment: Copper that has a silver looking coating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Tinned copper is fine to splice the same way as ordinary copper

Tinned copper (silvery on the outside, copper-colored on the inside, oft stranded) is fine to splice using copper-rated splices.  This is not to be confused with aluminum (silvery all the way through) which requires special splicing (Alumiconns or AlxCu mechanical connectors), or copper-clad aluminum (copper-colored on the outside, silvery on the inside) which also is OK to use with copper-rated splices, but needs to be treated as aluminum with regards to wire gauge.

Answer (score 1):

So you have 2 questions tinned copper and copper are fine to combine no problems there but copper and aluminum are a totally different type of connection requiring the use of special connectors.
With aluminum and copper the junction will fail if not done properly causing a fire hazard. Tinned copper and copper a wire nut is fine. Look up aluminacon connectors for aluminum to copper connections.

Comment: I do not have 2 questions.  I have a statement and a question.